# Find a winning strategy and determine which player will be the winner.

Tags: probability

On a table there are $100$ tokens.  Taking turns two players remove $5$,  $6$,  $7$,  $8$,  $9$ or $10$ tokens, at their choice.  The player that removes the last token wins.  Find a winning strategy and determine which player will be the winner.

This is one of the questions we presented in one session to contest preparation PUTNAM. It turns out that I can't get from the problem. Could someone just give me a hint? (Please, don't give me the answer. Simply, an argument that can help me advance in the problem or theorem might suffice.)

Comment: To clarify:  what happens if there are fewer than $5$ tokens remaining?  Is that a draw?  Or does "The player that removes the last token" mean, "whoever is the last one to make a legal move"?

Comment: These are only guesses. We do not consider the case where there are less than 5 tokens or the game is zero.  "The player That Removes the last token". For me, this means that the person who picked up the last token wins. For example, if there are 11 tokens to take and it is the turn of my opponent, so I am sure to win because he must take at least 5 tokens and at most 10 tokens. That is, it will stay between 1 and 6 tokens that I can perfectly pick up.

Comment: Not following.  If your opponent is facing 11 tokens and takes, say, 7 that will leave 4 and you have no allowed moves.

Comment: Hint:  Think in terms of $a+b=15$.

Comment: You are right.  if there are 15 tokens to take and it is the turn of my opponent, so I am sure to win because he must take at least 5 tokens and at most 10 tokens. That is, it will stay between 5 and 10 tokens that I can perfectly pick up.

Comment: If they are playing for money, and Bob is a little dim, it might be a good idea for Alicia to make a few suboptimal moves, and even lose occasionally, so that Bob can be induced to play more than one game.

Comment: Here if there are fewer than 5  tokens remaining,  that is a draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Think in terms of the equation $a+b=15$.

Added: Now that the hint has been understood, for completeness A's first move is to take away $10$.

Comment: I found the strategy when I started, for example. But if my opponent starts, how is it possible that I mayest win the game?. Are there a good strategy for me to win, despite the fact that my opponent starts the game?

Comment: The question asked who has the winning strategy, and what is it. We know the answer to that. If B starts, and he plays the winning strategy, then A is helpless. If B does not play the winning strategy, A can try to get back to multiples of $15$. But now we bump into the problem of what are the rules if a certain player is confronted with $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$. We have to make a decision about who wins then, or is it a draw. If it is a draw, I think the second player can force it unless the first player plays the winning strategy.